# Поиск и замента ссылки на сайте JS

Tags: javascript, search

Этим кодом я нахожу ссылку (https://site.am/en/services) на сайте и меняю её на `#`, но на странице есть несколько таких ссылок и меняются все.

Как сделать так, чтобы изменялась только первая найденная ссылка?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a').each(function (index) {
        if (this.href.indexOf("https://site.am/en/services") == 0) {
            // изменяем все ссылки кроме тех что содержат этот домен
            this.href = "#";
            return;
        } 
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Используйте для доступа к ссылке индекс вместо each: `$('a')[0]` или `$("a[href^='https://site.am/en/services']")` для поиска ссылки с конкретным содержимым. P.S.: я не уверен, что первая найденная ссылка будет первой в документе. Более конкретней по селектору: https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors

Comment: А зачем тогда делать цикл? Делаю выборку, ты получаешь массив элементов, отфильтруй его по ключевому параметру и возьми первый элемент.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   const target = document.querySelector(`a[href="https://site.am/en/services"]`); //Найдет первый элемент с такими параметрами
   if (target) target.setAttribute('href', '#');
});
```